# Phonegap www folder and optimization issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm working on a phonegap project and I've lot of css, js files. I've placed those css, js files in the `css`, `js` sub directories under `www` folder. I'm planning to use require js optimization tool to concatenate and minify the css and js files. The minified js and css files are placed in a separate folder called `dist` under `www`.

```
MyPhonegapProject
       |
       |__ www 
            |
            |__ css (contains unminified css files)
            |__ js  (contains unminifies js files)
            |__ dist (contains minified js and css files)
            |__ index.html (references minified js and css files from the dist folder)
```

Now my question in on kicking the phonegap build does everything inside the `www` folder are copied? I don't want the unminified the js and css files to be copied to the build folder. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create and work in a `src` directory and copy the (dist) files you need to the `www` directory before kicking off the build.

I'd recommend using a task runner, like Grunt - http://gruntjs.com to automate this for you.

Here's an example Gruntfile.js I've thrown together that you can use as a template. It cleans the `www` directory, copies all files from `src` to `www`, removes the unminified files from `www` and then kicks off the `cordova build` cli command:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),
        shell: {
            build: {
                // Run the cordova build command
                command: "cordova build"
            }
        },
        copy: {
            main: {
                // Copy all files from src to www
                src: ["**/*"],
                dest: "www/",
                expand: true,
                cwd: "src/"
            }
        },
        clean: {
            www: {
                // Remove all files currenty in the www dir
                src: ["www"]
            },
            js: {
                // Remove unminified js etc
                src: ["www/js/*.js"]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-copy");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-shell");

    grunt.registerTask("build", ["clean:www", "copy", "clean:js", "shell"]);
};
```

You can add whatever else you need for your workflow.

Comment: I've added a sample Gruntfile.js to use as a template